# Need character that will provide a thin space in ios iphone 6

Tags: php, html, ios, iphone, spaces

I need a character like & nbsp; for a thin space that will work on a iphone 6.  I've tried unicode characters but they don't seem to work.

I'm sending an email from php and I use the following:

```
$skipper = trim($skipper[0]) . '&#2009' . trim($skipper[1]);
```

and later place $skipper inside a div.  The thin space shows up in outlook but not on my iphone

Comment: Work where, how? Provide more specific details about what you need and what you have tried.

Comment: updated as requested, any ideas?